# "separate hsv"-node is giving a wrong output

Tags: node-editor, color, color-management

I have a color with a value of 1 and a saturation of 0.3. But if i connect them to a *Separate HSV node*, the output for the Saturation is 0.54, and it changes if i change the value.

Can someone explain this rather strange behavior?
I am very confused and will be thankful for any kind of an answer!

[image]

[example-video on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/kplbpk/hi_i_hope_yall_can_help_me_with_this_one_so_i/)

Comment: Oh, this is weird :). Because if you skip the Math node and plug it directly as a color, it doesn't change at all (just as it should)...

Comment: I think the separate hsv node I think is working fine, it's the RGB node that gives value difficoult to interpeter....

Comment: Which b3d version were you using in making the gif @JachymMichal? I'm not able to reproduce that behaviour in the current 2.92. BTW there are a few recent commits on this topic, so I think they are still working on it: https://developer.blender.org/rBf193b1afb313bcb937a396f09da2b9903a0d2fc3

Comment: Hey @Carlo :). I tried all from 2.8 to 2.9. It might've been fixed in recent versions.

Comment: BTW I've open a topic on devtalk: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/inconsistency-between-slider-and-color-picker/16920